# Can't get RelativeLayout to work in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having problems using a RelativeLayout in a ListView.  I would like to have the two EditText fields one above the other, instead they completely overlap one another.  I have more text to put in each row, so side by side isn't an option.

I tried taking out all extraneous code to make it work, so this is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/time"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: your 2nd edittext should have android:layout_below="@+id/time".

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
android:layout_below="@id/subject"
```

With

```
android:layout_below="@+id/time"
```

> So That EditText with id room will be below to EditText with id time.

Comment: @hotveryspicy OP has edited his question.Would you please mind to carefully review the edits before downvoting the answers,or you enjoy doing it?.OP had given some other id before instead of @id/time.

Comment: I think @VipulShah is correct from his side, and he also pointed out actual thing which messes up the view.one should read the requirements and the edits made before downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace android:layout_below="@id/subject"
to android:layout_below="@+id/time"

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout for this use case

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/room"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```